# How do I get the woocommerce product price via functions.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am curretly trying to create a shortcode that shows 3 products and the snippet looks like this:

```
function show_recent_products(){

    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type' => 'product');

    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) { 
    echo '<div id="recent-posts" class="flex space-between">';

    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) { 

        $custom_query->the_post(); 
        echo '<div class="woocommerce_recent_products" style="background: url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().')">';

            echo '<p>';
            //echo get_regular_price();
            echo'</p>';

        echo '</div>';

    }
    echo '</div>';
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

How can I get hold of the product price?

Reason why I am not using the default recent products shortcode it because the layout looks completely different and I would not know how to change the default code.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch product detail from ID. Use `wc_get_product()`. This will return Product Object.

```
$current_product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
```

After that you can use this object `$current_product` and fetch relevant product information using its methods like `get_price()`. Example.

```
echo $current_product->get_price();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the global product inside the while loop and with I managed to get hold of all the product information.

```
function show_recent_products(){
    global $post;

    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type' => 'product');
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) { 
    echo '<div id="recent-posts" class="flex space-between">';

    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) { 

        $custom_query->the_post(); 
        global $product;
            echo '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" class="woocommerce_recent_products flex align-center" style="background: url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().')">';

            echo '<div class="recent-content-inner">';
                echo '<div>';
                    echo '<p class="recent-add-title">';
                        echo get_the_title();
                    echo'</p>';
                    echo '<p class="recent-add-price">';
                        echo "R". $product->price;
                    echo'</p>';
                    echo '<p class="recent-add-cart">';
                        echo "ADD CART";
                    echo'</p>';
                echo'</div>';
            echo'</div>';

            echo "</a>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```